# How can I write an aws lambda function triggered both by alexa and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

now I am writing an Alexa skill.

Here is the simplified scheme I am trying to make work:

Alexa A --> lambda A --> SQS --> my service (interact with some stuff) --> DynamoDB

lambda A --> Alexa A

The problem is that I have two event source in lambda A, I can't figure out how to handle alexa source and DDB source in one handler.

Answer (score 1):

lambda A --> Alexa A is not possible. Alexa can only trigger a lambda synchronously and there is no way to do push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the other response yesterday and just today Amazon announced push notifications are coming soon. Sign up for this to be notified: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/8cc45487-d5fb-413b-b6c7-eeea4794d10c/amazon-announces-notifications-for-alexa-feature-is-coming-soon-sign-up-to-stay-tuned